# Under construction page using PHP and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I work now on one project. The point is to allow only specific users to view the progress of the project, so I create the `.HTACCESS` file and `domain.com/maintenance` page. In the `.HTACCESS` file I entered code for remove **.PHP** extension and code for allow only specific **IP** address to view the project. Everything working fine but without style, javascript files. My `.HTACCESS` file:

```
# Remove .php extension
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# Under maintenance mode with resource files /css /images etc...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.456.789
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/*.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/maintenance [R=307,L]
```

The folder where is assets files is in the **PUB** directory. Where is the problem? How I can resolve this problem?

Note: 123.456.789 change it to your IP Address and /pub/ directory is my directory where I place assets folders for CSS, Images, JS...

Comment: What part doesn't work? Could you provide examples that don't work?

Comment: Style - Look at maintenance.php don't work. When I open the website and open it to check source code and open any of the CSS files I get again that website is under construction. I think i need to give permission to folder pub to be visible or allow to be readable. Because I guess if I restrict to allowed IP address pub directory are closed for all only for specific IP Address I entered in .htaccess file. @MaartenDev

Comment: It rarely is a good idea to use the `MultiView` feature together with a rewriting rule like the first one in your configuration file.